# Comparing means with unequal n

Tags: r, regression, anova, t-test, group-differences

I am trying to compare two groups to see if they are statistically different in how much time in seconds ($y$) they use one of two particular products $x_1$ or $x_2$. One person can only use either $x_1$ or $x_2$.

$x_1$: $n$ = 173,301, mean = 6,487, std.dev = 16,355

$x_2$: $n$ = 18,043, mean = 10,859, std.dev = 21,275

What is the best way to find out if the two groups are different? I was thinking of using linear regression and look at the coefficients (e.g., `R`: `lm(y ~ x, data = ...)` but I can't remember ever using regression to compare two groups in this way when I took statistics many years ago so I'm guessing my thinking is wrong. Can I use ANOVA for this if I can't use regression?

Comment: The basic way of doing this is some kind of t-test. There are ways to phrase t-tests as regression or ANOVA (which actually is a type of regression), but that complicates what should not be a complicated problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What kind of t-test could I use for something like this? From what I can remember there´s a number of them for different purposes. I´m using regressions quite often so that´s probably why I was automatically thinking of regression for this, too..

Comment: Which t-tests do you see as options?

Comment: The two-sample independent t-test seems to be the most logical choice.

Comment: I would suggest the Welch variant of that test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on the distribution of your variables, X1 and X2. If they are approximately normally distributed, then it is reasonable to use a t-test. However, I see your handle is "Economist" and costs, for example, are often (? usually) skewed. If X1 and X2 are not approximately normally distributed, then a rank-based method is probably more appropriate, and the lead candidate would be the Wilcoxon rank sum test (a.k.a. Mann-Whitney U test).

`wilcox.test(x1, x1, alternative = 'two-sided')`

Do note that you could use linear regression (equivalent to ANOVA) for the normally distributed variables and quantile regression for the skewed variables, as an alternative.

Comment: The OP’s question doesn’t suggest the response is skewed, though it isn’t outside the realm of possibilities. Even if the shape of the distributions of $X_1$ and $X_2$ aren’t approximately bell-shaped, it shouldn’t be too worrisome with large $n$’s. Thus, while the *data* may be non-Normal, the sample *mean* in either group is very likely to be Normally distributed.

Comment: The distributions are closed to bell-shaped when taking the log.